# The meaning of Epydoc notations, L{ClassName} C{int}?

Tags: python, docstring, epydoc

While reading some others' code, I came across this type of docstring `@param reporter: A L{Reporter} instance, where ...` and figured out after some search that it's *Epydoc*. But what does these notations such as `L{ClassName?}` and `C{type?}` mean?

Comment: RTFEpydoc...? http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-epytext.html#documentation-crossreference-links

Answer (score 0):

From the [epydoc documentation](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-epytext.html),

- C{...}: Source code or a Python identifier. See [this](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-epytext.html#basic-inline-markup).
- L{...}: Documentation crossreference links. See [this](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/manual-epytext.html#documentation-crossreference-links).